# EnableCors on .Net Web Api works on local but not on server. Throws no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've followed this solution to fix my issue with .Net Web Api throwing no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

It perfectly works on my local machine when I run it and have another local app requests from it. But once I push the two apps on two different machines it throws the no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' again. I also tried pushing just the Web Api and running the other app from local and does the same thing. Obviously changing the value on "origins". Here's my code on the controller

```
public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:9292", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public string GetData(string database, string tableName, string query)
        {
          try{
            var data = List<MyObjects>();
            // fill my data;
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
          }catch(Exception ex){
             return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex);
          }
        }
}
```

This is my request: (written in angular)

```
$scope.testNewApi = function(){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://notlocalhost/ApiTest/api/Test/GetData?database=test&tableName=test2&query=test3'
            }).success(function (data, result) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
            }).error(function(err, result){
                console.log('error ' + err)
            });
        }
```

I have this setup as well on my webapiconfig, I tried "*" and I tried to specify the origin as well.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            EnableCrossSiteRequests(config);
        }

private static void EnableCrossSiteRequests(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
                origins: "*",
                headers: "*",
                methods: "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to configure your CORS on your server.

http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html

Comment: Yeah I actually had that already. I tried to mess with it as well but still no bueno.